# My css and png wont work on my 404 directory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, apache2, http-status-code-404

My css and png. work on regular errors but not when I do something like `localhost/example/example`. The css and png doesn't connect with the error page. It only works when I do something like `localhost/example`. My .htaccess looks like this by the way

```
ErrorDocument 400 /404
ErrorDocument 401 /404
ErrorDocument 403 /404
ErrorDocument 404 /404
ErrorDocument 500 /404
```

Comment: How are you linking to them in the error page? Using a relative path? It may need to be absolute if the server renders the 404 page without doing a real redirect to `/404`.

Comment: you the `<link>` in `<img>` tags on your 404 page